# How do you add type-property schemas from Schema.org into 8 sites?

Tags: 8

Some SEOers have reported good experience with enriching their websites with the formal schema vocabulary [Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html).

Is there any way to implement such schemas on Drupal 8 webpages?

### Update - July 9 2016:

Is it true to say to most of the functionality of this module got into the Drupal 8 core via the module Aggregator 8.x.x ? I read now in the modules' page (for Drupal 7 as linked in the answer) and that's what I understood; But if it did, then when why creating a new module is on the quine? It is written there the module has not yet been ported and that's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a Drupal 7 module of the same name, [schema.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/schemaorg).

> This project is a drop-in solution to enable the collections of
>   schemas available at schema.org on your Drupal 7 site. The major
>   search engines including Bing, Google and Yahoo! have agreed to
>   recognized these in order to improve the display of search results.

Along with the core module, there's a UI that makes it pretty easy to setup; you specify the schema.org type on the content type settings page & then you specify the schema.org property names on the field settings page. It also has support for [address field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) & [fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) fields.

In Drupal 8, the project has [deferred](https://www.drupal.org/node/2414073) to the [RDFUI](https://www.drupal.org/project/rdfui) project, to provide the UI component, now that other parts of the module have been ported to core.

> The default RDF mappings of Drupal core have been updated to include
>   schema.org in Drupal 8. Also, a lot of the backend code of this module
>   was ported into Drupal 8 core. The User Interface allowing to set the
>   mappings lives in the RDF UI, which is based on Sachini's Google
>   Summer of Code project.

Comment: Hi there Sahwn Conn. Is it true to say to most of the functionality of this module got into the Drupal 8 core via the module Aggregator 8.x.x ? I read now in the modules page (for Drupal 7 as linked above) and that's what I understood.

Comment: But if it did, then when why creating a new module is on the quine? It is written there the module has not yet been ported and that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Will reward for updated answer well.

Comment: It has been updated accordingly

Comment: Shawn, could you add just a small note in the end of the answer if there should be a dedicated module to Drupal 7 that will give more Schema.org options (I know that RDF isn't the only option) or someone should better work with the RDF way and there is no serious need for anyone to wait for a port of the D7 module?

Comment: I am just not sure if so much cover is the ultimate cover.

Comment: Like with many things Drupal, there's rarely a solution that covers all possible use cases. If there's any alternative that covers a different scenarios, I'll let someone cover that with a different answer. As for the port, it's already covered in the answer ("the projects has deferred"); there's not going to be one.

Comment: I admit I didn't quite knew the word "Deffered" in English... IIANW, I never used it before in English and don't find its interpretation with the Morfix dictionary. I thus assume it means "Changed".